# C++ program exits abnormally when outputting integers

Tags: c++, cout

I have this question in cout command in my computer. I use MingW and Netbeans for the learning of C++. I tried to compile and run a program with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << x + y << " " << x * y;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is saved as xycalculation.cpp and I compiled it using the command `g++ -o xycalc.exe xycalculation.cpp` on my Windows XP SP2 computer. 
I have this environment variables set in PATH. 
    C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;D:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;D:\MinGW\bin;D:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

This code compiles fine and creates the xycalc.exe file. and when i try to run it through the command line by `xycalc.exe`, it gives me a Windows error message and exit  without giving any output.

Details of the error, shown when I click the 'For more information about this error, click here' link is following.

```
AppName: xycalculation.exe   AppVer: 0.0.0.0     ModName: libstdc++-6.dll
ModVer: 0.0.0.0  Offset: 000952a0
```

Can anyone give me the directions to correct this issue?, it will be a great help for me to continue learning this language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for me (using `g++` on Mac OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` to your command line to static link the libs or put them in the same folder as the exe.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Wow! it did the thing. but do i have to set the `-static-libgcc` and -`static-libstdc++` commands every time i compile the sources?
Thanks again.

Comment: Are the libs in `D:\MinGW\lib`? Try adding that to PATH instead of statically linking.

Comment: To Jesse Good: It doesn't work. But adding the flags to the command line works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because by default your compiler won't compile `libstdc++` into your program.

I use codeblocks, but you can replicate the error by using the MinGW compiler and attempting to run the program outside of codeblocks in the console.

To fix this issue you should to add:

```
-static-libgcc (C) 
-static-libstdc++ (C++)
```

to your linker flags which will compile the libraries into your EXE (bigger EXE but it will run).

Comment: Is there a way to link only a smaller subset?  This generates a Hello World of over 1MB!!

Comment: @Allen hmm I'm sure if you made a custom lib with only what you needed you might be able to. But I've never attempted such a thing.

Comment: Strange, I've been playing with a simple "Hello, World!" program.  Whether I use "-static-libstdc++" or not, the output .exe requires libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll to be present or it throws an error.  If I use "-static-libstdc++" then the .exe becomes huge, but still won't run if that .dll isn't present.

Comment: @Allen that is quite odd... Maybe your IDE is compiling for a dynamic DLL but your compiler flags are statically linking the lib any way, so your code is looking for the DLL even though you have the lib linked statically. Though, if you want better help with this you could post a question with all your information (IDE, build options, etc.) and get better help than I can give in comments.

Comment: Let me try one more before forking to a different question and say that I'm not using an ide--just vim and g++ on the command-line (via MinGW/MinSYS).  Using a boilerplate hello.cpp (<iostream> and cout) and this command "g++ -o hello hello.cpp" (with and without "-static-libstdc++"), I get the behavior I've described.  Interestingly, if I do a hello.c with gcc (sans cout, of course), I get more "normal" results. (no dependency on the .dll)

Comment: @Allen The reason the C one without cout doesn't get the DLL error is because C doesn't use the cpp DLL, also, without `cout` there will be no dependency on the DLL anyway (the .h doesn't count when calculating dependencies, only calls to functions). My GCC is actually rejecting `-static-libstdc++`, so try just `-static` instead (and i can run the exe anyway so I can't debug this unfortunatly).